# How to change "+" to become "-" in Wordpress search page?

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

when searching `kevin mccarthy`, it automatically write in the URL:
`http://www.web.com/search/kevin+mccarthy`

but when I change `http://www.web.com/search/kevin+mccarthy` with `http://www.web.com/search/kevin-mccarthy`, no result appeared.

I have tried modify in `wp-includes/rewrite.php`
 but dont know what to replace

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to replace the `+` with a `-`? I don't know Wordpress well, but it looks like it's using the part after `/search/` as the RESTful equivalent of a query string and so is probably unencoding it in the same way. When a `+` appears in a query string, it equates to a space, and so the search would be for "kevin mccarthy" — but if you change it to a `-`, the search will be for "kevin-mccarthy" which seems like it probably isn't what you want... More on the specific URL encoding used in query strings on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type).